# Sysnchronized block program results are different from synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I have written a program on synchronized block by locking on .class, and my program is executing thread by thread. But when i write the same code using synchronized method, the output is entirely different.

Synchronized block program given below:

```
public class SyncBlock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Thread t1 = new SimpleThread("First Thread");
        final Thread t2 = new SimpleThread("Second Thread");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class SimpleThread extends Thread {
    public SimpleThread(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (SyncBlock.class) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(getName() + " says " + i);
                try {
                    sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            System.out.println(getName() + " is done.");
        }
    }
}
```

The out put is:

```
First Thread says 0
First Thread says 1
First Thread says 2
First Thread says 3
First Thread says 4
First Thread is done.
Second Thread says 0
Second Thread says 1
Second Thread says 2
Second Thread says 3
Second Thread says 4
Second Thread is done.
```

Now i am using the same program using synchronized method. But it is behaving differently. Could you please explain whether both will behave differently or is there **any solution to get same output using both synchronized block and method.**

Using synchronized method:

now synchronize the run method and replace this code:

```
public synchronized void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println(getName() + " says " + i);
                try {
                    sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            System.out.println(getName() + " is done.");
}
```

Here the output is different:

```
First Thread says 0
Second Thread says 0
Second Thread says 1
First Thread says 1
First Thread says 2
Second Thread says 2
First Thread says 3
Second Thread says 3
First Thread says 4
First Thread is done.
Second Thread says 4
Second Thread is done.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `synchronized` block you are locking class object which will lock execution of `run` method on other objects when one object has invoked it. But when you `synchronized` run method, you will lock object not class, so it will not block another thread to execute same method on another object. Hence both thread executes in parallel. 
 
 If you want to achieve same execution as with `synchronized` block you can have a `synchronized static` method which executes steps that are in run and call it from run method

Comment: is there any solution to execute one by one thread using synchronize method.

Comment: @Murali - In your *particular* case, no. Since your code is *independent*, you will need a Lock and you will have to sue that lock in both the places. So, this will require a synchronized block, a synchronized method will not work. Any method which you make synchronized will only affect either the class (static method) or the instance (non-static method) of `SimpleThread` class only.

Comment: @TheLostMind - Thank you. So In Synchronized method we are locking object thread, but at the same time another object thread can also be able to access the run method. this is what happening there?

Comment: @Murali -  yes. In your case, for each sync method, you are locking on the current object (this), so, there are 2 threads which are locking on *themselves*. So, the 2 threads can execute independently.

Comment: @Murali - you are welcome :). And yes, pallavi's answer is right as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use :  `synchronized (SyncBlock.class)`, your code works fine because you are locking on the SyncBlock class, so other thread cannot get access to the class Object of `SyncBlock` until the first one releases it.

In the second case, you are locking on the current instance of `SimpleThread`(this), the lock will be different for both threads (you are locking on the SimpleThread instances themselves). So, the lock itself is in-effective and the JVM might as well remove the synchronization code (from jdk6 U23 - *escape analysis* was introduced to optimize such things)

Answer (score 0):

In case of synchronized block say First thread enters first

```
synchronized (SyncBlock.class) {-->  // here First thread takes the lock now  no other thread can enter
```

Now when First thread reaches here

```
  System.out.println(getName() + " is done.");
    } --->  here First thread releases the lock  . So this gives chance to other thread which are waiting for this lock . so in ur case Second thread takes it and then executes it and when it reaches here it will release and then again other thread can take over. Note  : This behavior is not definite
```

Threads can execute in any manner Depends upon CPU scheduling policy

And what happens in synchronized method is  as soon as one thread enters this method it will complete its task and then release the lock .After this other thread gets the chance to execute .

Also note that **sleep doesnt release the LOCK** . at that stage thread is in wait state

Comment: Please look at the OPs code and answer. Though first part of your answer is right, the second part is unrelated to the Op's code / question.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers here is wrong, but none of them really speaks to the heart of the matter.

When you write `synchronized`, your code synchronizes on an Object, and the JVM guarantees that no two threads can be synchronized on the same object at the same time.

In your first example, the SimpleThread.run() method synchronizes on the unique SyncBlock class object.  That prevents both threads from entering run() at the same time because they both are trying to synchronize on the same object:  there is only one SyncBlock class object.

In your second example, the SimpleThread.run() method synchronizes on `this`.  That does *not* prevent the two threads from entering run() at the same time because the two threads are synchronizing on two *different* objects:  You create two instances of SimpleThread.